# systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I have log message from Systemd on every boot: `Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary`. How to fix it on Ubuntu 22.04.1?

syslog:

```
Jan  2 02:04:44 gnome-session[1330]: gnome-session-binary[1330]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Jan  2 02:04:44 gnome-session[1330]: gnome-session-binary[1330]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Jan  2 02:04:44 gnome-session-binary[1330]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Jan  2 02:04:44 gnome-session-binary[1330]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
```

Comment: Please share all relevant lines from the log. There should be a couple of lines prior to the posted message which may give a hint what goes wrong.

Comment: I found three lines "Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session binary", and one line before "Started Application launched by gnome session binary". No additional information. It is Journals Application Security Tab. I know the time the message was generated so I can see any other log file.

Comment: I added the syslog to the question. I deleted computer name from the log.